# Is there any good reason to not put composer in the path?

Tags: php, composer-php

In every tutorial I see using composer people are storing composer.phar somewhere and calling

```
php composer.phar
```

I've renamed composer.phar, I've putted it in my path so I can do:

```
composer
```

Is there any cons of using this approach?

Comment: Not actually, I did the same as you ^^

Comment: The only advantage i see storing the composer phar in the project directory is if you have multiple projects on a single machine you dont have to include the --working-dir option to specify which one you are working with every time as composer assumes the current working directory if one isnt provide. That being said I also install composer into my path so i can just call composer from the cli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you need different versions of composer for different projects, putting it in your path isn't a bad idea. Its normal for all the projects I work on, and composer themselves actually suggest it too on their [site](http://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally)

```
$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
$ mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```